# VB.Net - vbNewLine not functioning in email

Tags: vb.net

Having difficulty formatting an email I'm sending out. All the data I need is being returned, but some of the vbNewLines are not working.

Here's the code. Note that the large block here at the top works fine, including the & vbNewLine & vbNewLine double space at the end.

```
Dim arErrors As Array = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(String), 1000)

<<SQL select>>

odbcCmd = New OdbcCommand(strSQL.ToString, odbcConn)
odbcCmd.CommandTimeout = 100000
Rs = odbcCmd.ExecuteReader()
Do While Rs.Read
    If Len(Trim(Rs.Item("Cu_Rep_Id").ToString)) = 6 Then
        odbcCmd2 = New OdbcCommand(<<SQL Select>>)
        odbcCmd2.CommandTimeout = 100000
        Rs2 = odbcCmd2.ExecuteReader()
        If Rs2.HasRows Then
            If Trim(Rs2.Item("Rep_Job_Cd").ToString).IndexOf("SMIC REP,  SMIC - WAVERLY,  SALES REP - WAVERLY, SALES REP - MADISON") = -1 Then
                If CType(Rs2.Item("Rep_Term_Dt"), Date) < Now() Then
                    arErrors.SetValue("Difference for Rep: " & Trim(Rs.Item("Cu_Rep_Id").ToString) & " Navigator: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Data_Vl_Nr"), Decimal), 2) & " TruComp: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Data_Value"), Decimal), 2) & " Difference: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Diff"), Decimal), 2) & " (Rep terminated on " & Rs2.Item("Rep_Term_Dt").ToString & ")", intMax)
                    intMax = intMax + 1
                Else
                    arErrors.SetValue("Difference for Rep: " & Trim(Rs.Item("Cu_Rep_Id").ToString) & " Navigator: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Data_Vl_Nr"), Decimal), 2) & " TruComp: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Data_Value"), Decimal), 2) & " Difference: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Diff"), Decimal), 2), intMax)
                    intMax = intMax + 1
                End If
            Else
                arErrors.SetValue("Difference for SMIC Rep: " & Trim(Rs.Item("Cu_Rep_Id").ToString) & " Navigator: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Data_Vl_Nr"), Decimal), 2) & " TruComp: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Data_Value"), Decimal), 2) & " Difference: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Diff"), Decimal), 2), intMax)
                intMax = intMax + 1
            End If
        Else
            arErrors.SetValue("Difference for Unknown Rep: " & Trim(Rs.Item("Cu_Rep_Id").ToString) & " Navigator: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Data_Vl_Nr"), Decimal), 2) & " TruComp: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Data_Value"), Decimal), 2) & " Difference: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Diff"), Decimal), 2), intMax)
            intMax = intMax + 1
        End If
        Rs2.Close()

    ElseIf Len(Trim(Rs.Item("Cu_Rep_Id").ToString)) = 8 Then
        odbcCmd2 = New OdbcCommand(<<SQL Select>>)
        odbcCmd2.CommandTimeout = 100000
        Rs2 = odbcCmd2.ExecuteReader()
        If Rs2.HasRows Then
            If CType(Rs2.Item("Prog_End_Dt"), Date) < Now() Then
                arErrors.SetValue("Difference for CU: " & Trim(Rs.Item("Cu_Rep_Id").ToString) & " Navigator: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Data_Vl_Nr"), Decimal), 2) & " TruComp: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Data_Value"), Decimal), 2) & " Difference: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Diff"), Decimal), 2) & " CU Status: " & Rs2.Item("Cu_Status").ToString & " (CU terminated on " & Rs2.Item("Prog_End_Dt").ToString & ")", intMax)
                intMax = intMax + 1
            Else
                arErrors.SetValue("Difference for CU: " & Trim(Rs.Item("Cu_Rep_Id").ToString) & " Navigator: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Data_Vl_Nr"), Decimal), 2) & " TruComp: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Data_Value"), Decimal), 2) & " Difference: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Diff"), Decimal), 2) & " CU Status: " & Rs2.Item("Cu_Status").ToString, intMax)
                intMax = intMax + 1
            End If
        Else
            arErrors.SetValue("Difference for Unknown CU: " & Trim(Rs.Item("Cu_Rep_Id").ToString) & " Navigator: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Data_Vl_Nr"), Decimal), 2) & " TruComp: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Data_Value"), Decimal), 2) & " Difference: " & FormatCurrency(CType(Rs.Item("Diff"), Decimal), 2), intMax)
            intMax = intMax + 1
        End If
        Rs2.Close()
    Else
        If Trim(Rs.Item("Cu_Rep_Id").ToString) <> "" Then
            arErrors.SetValue("Invalid Ps_Nr or Contr_Nr: " & Trim(Rs.Item("Cu_Rep_Id").ToString), intMax)
            intMax = intMax + 1
        End If
    End If
Loop
Rs.Close()

If Dts.Variables("DeletedCount").Value <> "0" Then
    strBody = strBody & Dts.Variables("DeletedCount").Value & " records were removed from TruComp_Detail prior to load." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
End If
```

Again, the above vbNewLine & vbNewLine works perfect as a double space. Below is the offending loop that is giving me fits. The data is returned, but the & vbNewLine doesn't work.

```
intCount = 0
Do While intCount < intMax
    strBody = strBody & arErrors.GetValue(intCount).ToString & vbNewLine
    intCount = intCount + 1
Loop

strBody = strBody & "Process complete."
```

Comment: Those sql statements are vulnerable to sql injection attacks. This is practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Okay, the vulnerable code is deleted now from the question... but that wasn't the security problem. The code needs to be fixed! Please still do that!

Comment: Use <br /> instead. An email is in html format.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Joel. These haven't been looked at in years, and this is my first time being eyes-on with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

E-mails use HTML formatting, so you want to use `<br/>` instead.

```
Do While intCount < intMax
    strBody = strBody & arErrors.GetValue(intCount).ToString & "<br/>"
    intCount = intCount + 1
Loop
```

Comment: If that's the case, why does the & vbNewLine & vbNewLine at the end of the first section work?

Comment: @niclake That I honestly could not tell you. I just did a quick test in my own environment using a single and double `vbNewLine` for a label item, and it didn't place the text after them on a new line. However, concatenating a `<br />` in between the line caused the second half to break to a new line. From what I can tell through looking around, a browser won't interpret `vbNewLine` into a `<br />`, and will remove most whitespace automatically, including the newline character that `vbNewLine` creates.

Comment: It was probably wrapping naturally at the position, based the width of his e-mail client window.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yeah, there are likely many reasons both based on the code or other factors outside the code. Main thing is: if you're doing something that uses HTML formatting, you gotta output the proper HTML tags to format things correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same exact problem. I got around it by using a StringBuilder and the Append(System.Environment.Newline) method instead of regular string concatenation.

I don't know if it makes any difference, but I was using C#.

In my app a switch to HTML format wasn't feasible because there were a number of other emails sent from the app, all text formatted.